# Http Cache control headers for files with different extensions

Tags: javascript, http-headers, browser-cache

I have issue with Cache Control headers for files with different extensions. I have a file `abc.do` which is a dynamically generated javascript file. I am trying to Implement cache control headers for this file but with no luck so my question is does this headers only apply for files with .js or .css extensions(static files only) ? Or is there any technique that can be applied for dynamically generated content?

Comment: I think you missed some infos about webserver or server language :)

Comment: Idk if it matters but Its Java and Jboss on server side.